# How should I understand the nuances between "astringent" and "acerbic"

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I keep on getting these two words mixed up in my head. How should I understand the nuances that distinguish "astringent" and "acerbic"? Is there ever a reason to use one over the other? The definitions have a ton of parallels with some subtle differences.

From the New Oxford American Dictionary...

**astringent:**

> - (of taste or smell) slightly acidic or bitter
> - sharp or severe in manner or style

**acerbic:**

> - (archaic or technical) tasting sour or bitter.
> - (especially of a comment or style of speaking) sharp and forthright

Comment: [Acerbic](https://www.lexico.com/definition/acerbic) is usually descriptive of *people* while [astringent](https://www.lexico.com/definition/astringent) is – but not always – applied to *things*.

Comment: They're both taste metaphors. Which one do you prefer -- mango or mangosteen?

Comment: Well, I'd rather be known as acerbic than astringent.  I think *astringent* is a bit farther out there on the sour axis.

Answer (score -2):

Let's look at the etymology, to uncover the original meaning:

**Astringent** is from mid 16th century: from French, from Latin astringent- ‘pulling tight’, from the verb astringere, from ad- ‘towards’ + stringere ‘bind, pull tight’.

An astringent is a liquid or compound that causes the contraction of skin cells and other body tissues, as in "an astringent facial toner"

Easy to remember - think of 'a string' pulling something tight. An astringent for example, a facial toner, pulls the skin tight.

Example:

I use witch hazel as an astringent to tone my face after moisturiser.

Note: the thing about an astringent is - it stings your face. As can an 'astringent' comment.

Remember it as 'a string' that can sting'

**Acerbic**

Is from the mid 19th century: from Latin acerbus ‘sour-tasting’ or acidic.

Which also can sting.

Remember it as 'ACerbic is ACidic'.

These words when applied to 'wit' or 'a comment' then mean:

**An astringent comment**  - made my face sting - could also mean 'refreshing' like a splash of cold water. Is bracing.

**An acerbic comment** - acidic, bitter, stinging

Comment: The OP is not seeking an explanation of the meaning of each of these words **considered on its own**; the question itself contains their dictionary definitions. The OP is asking for the **difference** between their meanings (if any) to be **made explicit**.

Comment: The definitions given by the op are incorrect. I have given correct definitions based on etymology. As he said he 'couldn't remember the differences' I gave a mnemonic to remind him.

Comment: For clarity, I have edited my answer to include what 'an astringent' actually is.